# Image file validation in PHP (Size - Type)

Tags: php

Im trying to check an image before uploading it. It's working fine with type but when i try to upload a picture of size larger than 2mb it returns the same error of type .. anyone can help !?

```
<?php
if ($_FILES)

{
    $imageName = date("hms").$_FILES['logo']['name'];

    if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name']))

    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('من فضلك اختار صورة')</script>";
    }

    elseif (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']))
    {
        if($_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/jpeg'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/JPEG'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/jpg'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/JPG'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/gif'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/GIF'
        && $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/png'
        &&  $_FILES['logo']['type'] != 'image/PNG')
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('يرجى إدخال صورة من امتداد jpeg, jpg, gif, png فقط')</script>";
            }

        elseif(($_FILES['logo']['size'] >2087152))
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('اقصى حجم للصورة 2 ميجابايت')</script>";
            }

        else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], "styles/images/$imageName");
                mysql_query("UPDATE components SET path='$imageName' WHERE type='logo'");
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('تم رفع الصورة بنجاح')</script>";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

if it is your server

Open your *php.ini* (linux: */etc/php.ini*, windows: *C:\WINDOWS* or *C:\WINNT*) and change or add the following piece of code:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files
upload_max_filesize = 4M
```

Save your php.ini and restart your server

OR

[upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)  (in php.ini or .htaccess only, won't work using ini_set())

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` can _not_ bet set using `ini_set`, it is changeable PHP_INI_PERDIR.

Comment: Thnx for help but, i changed the code but when i try to upload image greater than 2 mb it alert me with messg of the image type !! i want to alert that u can't upload more than 2 mb messg as it appears im my code !!

Comment: sorry i didn't understand the next half part of your previous comment??

Comment: When i trying to upload picture more than 2 mb i got an alert of image extension not alert of size that i specified

Comment: can you print screen your error msg and share it here?